# SQL Query: customer name including activity count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

There's probably a very simple solution to this that I'm not seeing right now.

I need a script for an SQL report. I can get all customer names in a simple SELECT:

```
SELECT
    t5.[Name] AS CustomerName
FROM
    [T5] t5
WHERE
    t5.Type IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY
    t5.[Name]
```

This gives me an ordered list for the dropdown menu, to select the customer name. The result set looks like this:

```
CustomerName
------------
Customer 1 Name
Customer 2 Name
Customer 3 Name
...
```

But I don't just need the name, I need the number of related activities to that customer name inside the name string as well. For example, with 38 activities for that customer it should look like : "(38) Customer Name here"

The statement giving me the correct count for *one* particular customer (in this example, "Customer 5 Name") looks something like this, it needs a couple of joins to get there:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [T1] t1
INNER JOIN
    [T2] t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[Activity]
INNER JOIN
    [T3] t3 ON t3.[ID] = t2.[Username]
INNER JOIN
    [T4] t4 ON t4.[ID] = t3.[ID]
INNER JOIN
    [T5] t5 ON t5.[ID] = t4.[X]
WHERE
    t5.[Name] = 'Customer 5 Name'
```

Now obviously I need to combine these somehow, to get the following result set:

```
CustomerName
-------------------
(a) Customer 1 Name
(b) Customer 2 Name
(c) Customer 3 Name
(d) Customer 4 Name
(e) Customer 5 Name
(f) Customer 6 Name
...
```

(a-f being the respective activity count for that customer)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your query just needs a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WITH pre AS
    (
    SELECT  t5.[Name] AS CustomerName,  COUNT(*) AS ActivityCount
    FROM [T1] t1 
    INNER JOIN [T2] t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[Activity] 
    INNER JOIN [T3] t3 ON t3.[ID] = t2.[Username] 
    INNER JOIN [T4] t4 ON t4.[ID] = t3.[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [T5] t5 ON t5.[ID] = t4.[X] 
    WHERE t5.Type IN (1, 2) AND t5.[Name] = 'Customer 5 Name'
    GROUP BY t5.Name
    )

    SELECT '(' + ActivityCount + ') ' + CustomerName
    FROM pre
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `group by`

```
SELECT
    t5.[Name], COUNT(*)
FROM
    [T1] t1
INNER JOIN
    [T2] t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[Activity]
INNER JOIN
    [T3] t3 ON t3.[ID] = t2.[Username]
INNER JOIN
    [T4] t4 ON t4.[ID] = t3.[ID]
INNER JOIN
    [T5] t5 ON t5.[ID] = t4.[X]
group by t5.[Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will give you the number with the customer name as per your requirement.

```
  SELECT
         '(' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS nvarchar(4) ) + ') '  +    t5.[Name] as [CustomerName]
        FROM
            [T1] t1
        INNER JOIN
            [T2] t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[Activity]
        INNER JOIN
            [T3] t3 ON t3.[ID] = t2.[Username]
        INNER JOIN
            [T4] t4 ON t4.[ID] = t3.[ID]
        INNER JOIN
            [T5] t5 ON t5.[ID] = t4.[X]
        group by t5.[Name]
```